# Updating Web2py's auto_increment id with filled database?

Tags: python, postgresql, web2py

i'm working on a web2py project and i need to insert 500+ rows of data to a database.

The problem is that if i use Pgadmin to do this using 'Insert' web2py auto_increment id, it doesn't recognizes the data and tries to insert new rows using the KEY 1 which leads to an REPEATED PRIMARY KEY ERROR.

Is there a better way to insert the data initially or modifying the starting auto_increment id value?

UPDATE:

I've defined and created the table on Web2py like this,

```
db.define_table('Client_Size',
            Field('name', 'string'))
```

After running it one time web2py created it on the db, and then, using Pgadmin III, interted values like this,

```
INSERT INTO Client_Size(id, name) VALUES
(1, 'Small'), (2, 'Medium'), (3, 'Big');
```

This is a short input, but i have another with 500 values so manual input is not a possibility.

After that, if i try to add a new row to `Client_Size` web2py doesn't recognize that the db has been filled with data, and uses the id as 1, creating the error.

Comment: Was this an existing table, or did web2py create it? If the former, are you sure the id field is an auto incrementing integer field?

Comment: I've defined all tables on web2py, and then added the rows using pgadmin, from there, if i try to add a new row it says that the key already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` field is an auto-incrementing integer field, which means the database will automatically fill it in with the next value. So, you should not be attempting to insert your own values for that field -- just specify the value of the `name` field and let the database handle creation of the `id`. (Even if it were not auto-incrementing, because it serves as the primary key for the table, you wouldn't want to insert duplicate values anyway.)

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem, just inserting the values without the id. I thought web2py handled the incrementing field.

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to accept the answer. :-)